# ngrx actions with optional payload

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm working with Angular 8 and NgRx 8, is it possible create an action with optional payload?
I'm trying to do something like:

```
export const MyAction = createAction('[Action ] MyAction', props<{ prop?: string }>());
```

but unfortunately doesn't work.
Could you help me?

Comment: I’m afraid this is not possible. I had the exact same issue - I simply passed on the empty object. But your question drove me to ask a specialist and he confirmed that it is probably not possible. The best and cleanest option really seems to be to either sent the empty object OR just create 2 actions - one with and another one without props. https://twitter.com/dutch_guy/status/1252207780213088256?s=21

Comment: @Vinni it is possible. Look on my comment bellow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to make the keys in the payload optional, but not the payload object itself. So the solution can be like this, where we want the error in the payload object to be optional.

```
export const listenForFeatureFailure = createAction(
    '[Feature] listen for feature Failure',
    props<{ error?: any }>()
);
```

And in your effects you can call it with or without the `error`

```
...
ProductSubscriptionActions.listenForFeatureAccessUpdatedFailure({error});
// or
ProductSubscriptionActions.listenForFeatureAccessUpdatedFailure({});
```

Answer (score 13):

Based on [this post](https://medium.com/@gregor.woiwode/ngrx-8-meet-the-new-upcoming-factory-methods-of-the-next-major-release-a97a079cc089) there is an optional payload definition.

Example:

```
export const FetchPlayersAction = createAction(
  '[Players.List] FETCH_PLAYERS',
  (payload: ListingOptions = {}) => payload, // defined optional payload
);
```

Comment: looks like it should be `(payload: ListingOptions = {}) => ({payload})` based on the article

Comment: @satanTime it is up to you and your usage :) But ye if article is source. I need it like it is in example :)

Answer (score 6):

Based on your example, you can set a default value, and then it's optional:

```js
export const MyAction = createAction(
  '[Action ] MyAction',
  (prop: string = 'My default value') => ({ prop })
);
```